# google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb file could not be opened?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using 64 bit ubuntu 11.10. I am trying to install the google chrome web browser by downloading "google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb" file but when i try to open it by using ubuntu software center it is saying that that .deb file could not be opened. little help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First download Chromium from the Ubuntu Software Centre then remove it.  Then try installing Google Chrome.

P.S. Chromium is basically the same as Chrome, just it is open-sourced!  :)

Comment: This is the easiest way to successfully accomplish installing the dependencies that are missing.  See the other answer for *why* this solution works.

Answer (score 5):

If you run

```
sudo dpkg -i <packagename>
```

and it fails because of dependencies, you can always try running apt-get with -f the "fix" it.

This usually works.

```
sudo apt-get -f --force-yes --yes install
```

If I recall correctly, dpkg actually logs what dependencies are missing and *apt-get -f* catches this and will try to install them. This do require, of course, that the dependencies are available in your currently configured repositories.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and running the command `sudo apt-get -f install` resolved some dependency problems and I was able to install it using `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`.

Answer (score 1):

i am assuming that you have downloaded the right package ..i.e you have amd processor and 64 bit OS. Always there is better way.. but i assumed that you know what you doing & you question was there is error when you are trying to install downloaded chrome package from google.

it is better if you do it from terminal... sometimes ubuntu software center doen't work..

type
 `sudo dpkg -i packagename`

.. you may see dependency error of libcur3

this is common bug when you install chrome from google(sometimes) & **this is only for your information**,

To solve this you need to install following dependencies

`sudo apt-get install libcurl3`

`sudo apt-get install libnspr4-0d`

`sudo apt-get install libplc4-0d`

`sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d`

and finally:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issues while installing chrome on my Ubuntu 22.04. Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. I clicked on this link and it downloaded deb file in my downloads folder https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
2. cd Downloads
3. sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
4. Opened installed applications and added Chrome to my favorites :)

Terminal screenshot:

[image: Terminal image]