# Unable to install "google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb" pakage?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, google-chrome, dpkg

```
~$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb  
dpkg: error
processing archive google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb (--install):
package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386) Errors were
encountered while processing:  google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**Also did:**

```
~$ sudo dpkg --install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb   
dpkg:
error processing archive google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
(--install):  package architecture (amd64) does not match system
(i386) Errors were encountered while processing: 
google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**And Also did:**

```
~$ wget
https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
--2016-05-27 11:37:16--  https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
Resolving dl-ssl.google.com (dl-ssl.google.com)... 74.125.68.93,
74.125.68.91, 74.125.68.136, ... Connecting to dl-ssl.google.com (dl-ssl.google.com)|74.125.68.93|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2016-05-27
11:37:16 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

**What is the exact issue? is anyone there to help me out!!!**

**Note**: i386 package is not available anymore,anyone there to help me out regarding this issue. Sometimes Ubuntu sounds frustrated, what to do with these kinds of issue.

Used few links to troubleshoot but not resolving with those:
[How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)
[google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb file could not be opened?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87344/google-chrome-stable-current-amd64-deb-file-could-not-be-opened)

Comment: "package architecture (amd64) does not match system"? Are you trying to install the amd64 package on i386?

Comment: It seems like you are running a 32bit system. You can't install 64bit software on 32bit systems. Google offers only 64bit releases and as a result of that you won't get any new versions of Google Chrome for that installation.

Comment: If this is a new installation and your hardware is 64 bit compatible, consider doing a reinstall using a 64bit image of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you but my system is 64 bit(i just tried 32 bit may be it works!!)

Comment: may I suggest that u use Chromium instead? It still supports 32bit architectures (i386)

Answer (score 0):

You can do nothing.

Google decided to stop supporting 32bit with Chrome.
So, either you move to a 64bit system, or you stop using Google Chrome.

It is a company (Google) choice and the only thing that the community can help you with, is giving you alternatives (like the open source Chromium Browser, on which Google Chrome is based).

Answer (score 0):

### You can install Chromium instead.

Chromium is the Open-Source development version of Google Chrome. It features less out-of-the-box (i.e. you may need to install some codecs yourself) but functionally is the same as Google Chrome.

To do this, open up the Terminal and simply type,

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Input your password at prompt and let it install. When it's done, you should be able to open it from the Unity menu (Start menu, if you will) and log in if you have a Google account. That's it.

As I'm sure you're aware, Google stopped supporting Chrome for 32-bit (x32; i386) systems to keep current, but Chromium still supports these older systems.